# Can't get textwidth for syntax highlighting working

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-fortran

I have a bunch of (spagetti) fortran code that is in fixed form, but without the line length restrictions. As such, it gets some odd highlighting:

[image: Standard highlighting]

I've tried 3 different ways to get it to highlight correctly, but none of them work.

1. Add `setlocal textwidth=132` to `.vimrc`
2. Add `let fortran_free_source=1; setlocal comments=:!,:*,:C,:c` to `.vimrc`
3. Create new syntax file that implements both the above changes for `fortran_free_source=1` and `fortran_fixed_source=1`.

Option 1 does nothing. Option 2 doesn't recognize `C` as a comment string. Option 3 also does nothing.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Edit: Also, running `:verbose set [setting]?` in all the above cases returns the expected result (ie. For option 1, it'll say that `textwidth=132` and that it was set from `.vimrc`)

Comment: What's the extension of the file? Try this: `syn clear fortranSerialNumber`. Or try to add `let g:fortran_has_tabs = 1` to your vimrc. Looking at the syntax file for Fortran, that's what I came up with...

Comment: `syn clear fortranSerialNumber` worked! The extension of the file is `*.f`. I'm not sure why it does (feel free to add to add an answer and I'll mark it as correct). @filbranden

Comment: Also, for stragglers, this SO answer is probably helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9505434/7564988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Fortran syntax file, I could find that the source of that highlighting past column 72 is coming from [this rule on line 358](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/fortran.vim#L358):

```
syn match fortranSerialNumber excludenl "^.\{73,}$"lc=72
```

As you can see, columns 73 and 72 are hardcoded into this rule, so setting `'textwidth'` will not really affect this particular rule and won't really work to fix this.

(You can also see this rule is defined inside a `if (b:fortran_fixed_source == 1)` and the `ftplugin/fortran.vim` file [sets this buffer variable](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/ftplugin/fortran.vim#L37-L39) for files with the `.f`, `.f77` or `.for` extensions. That also matches your comment regarding the extension of your file.)

In order to work around this, one option is to undo the effect of that particular rule, which you can do by clearing it after the syntax file is loaded.

To do that, you can create a new file `~/.vim/after/syntax/fortran.vim` and add the following line there:

```
syn clear fortranSerialNumber
```

This will undo the syntax highlighting past column 72 in your Fortran files. Placing the file being in the `after/` directory ensures it's loaded after the main syntax highlighting rules, so it will have a rule to delete there.

See [`:help mysyntaxfile-add`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile-add) for more details on customizing syntax rules in Vim.

Please note that this change will affect *all* Fortran files (more specifically, fixed source ones, which use this rule.) If you want something more localized, to a single project only, you might need to do some adjustments to only remove the rule depending on the specific file. (An option to consider to implement this is to use an alternative file type, on the `'filetype'` setting, that will source the `fortran.vim` files and add modifications. Another option is to use multiple filetypes in `'filetype'`, separated by a dot `.`, so you can keep `fortran` and add one more for your specific customizations.)

---

There's one more option to consider. Looking around the definition of the `fortranSerialNumber`, it's inside a block that checks that the `fortran_have_tabs` variable is unset (presumably because if you're using tab characters, it's harder to check for a specific column, since tab sizes can vary.)

So you might be able to prevent the definition of this rule by adding this to your vimrc:

```
let g:fortran_have_tabs = 1
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can simply configure it from your vimrc file, no need to mess with anything inside the `~/.vim` tree.

On the other hand, setting this will have a few other side effects. There are two other rules inside that block that won't get set (the rules seem to highlight errors in labels, which seem to be expected in specific columns.) There's also another rule regarding tab characters themselves. If you're fine with these side effects (considering you're breaking some rules by going past column 72, I guess you might?), then consider this as a possible solution for the issue as well.